# AWS Beanstalk Error 504 Timeout on Python Flask Application

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, mod-wsgi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Python Flask application on AWS Bean stalk. I have decent experience in python but totally new to deployments. I've been getting an error which says " *url*  took too long to respond HTTP 504 ". My environment's health is totally fine and all my deployments to the instance doesn't indicate any errors, yet I seem to be getting this 504 issue

Error looks like this:

[Error 504](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiDZ2.jpg)

Error Log looks like this:
[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqh0j.jpg)

Access Log:
[Access Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o7u8.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
  from flask_restful import Resource, Api

  import firebase_admin

  # For connecting to firestore database and authentication
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

 # For Cross-Origin Http requests
 from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

 # For Data base Connectivity
 from firebase_admin import db

 from flask import jsonify

  application = app = Flask(__name__)
  api = Api(app)


 CORS(app)

 class Firebase_Data(Resource):

     def get(self):

         return self._getData()

        def _getData(self):

         # Setting up credentials to connect
    cred = credentials.Certificate(****)

    # Setting up secure connection to firestore Real time database

        Kokomo_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'projectId' : '****'
       })


      # Connecting to the firestore client
    db_ref = firestore.client()

      # Referring to a section of the data
    ref_inc = db_ref.collection(****)

      # Fetching all the records under that particular section and converting 
       them to list of dictionaries
    docs = list( ref_inc.get() )



     lat_long = []

     for doc in docs:

        data = doc.to_dict()

        lat_long.append(

              { 'Latitude:' : data['latitude'], 'Longitude' : 
              data['longitude'] } )


       return lat_long


    api.add_resource(Firebase_Data, '/Firebase_Data') # Route_1

   if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run()
```

My requirements file:

```
aniso8601==4.0.1

CacheControl==0.12.5

cachetools==3.0.0

certifi==2018.10.15

chardet==3.0.4

Click==7.0

firebase-admin==2.13.0

Flask==1.0.2

Flask-Cors==3.0.7

Flask-RESTful==0.3.6

google-api-core==1.5.2

google-auth==1.6.1

google-cloud-core==0.28.1

google-cloud-firestore==0.30.0

google-cloud-storage==1.13.0

google-resumable-media==0.3.1

googleapis-common-protos==1.5.5

grpcio==1.16.1

idna==2.7

itsdangerous==1.1.0

Jinja2==2.10

MarkupSafe==1.1.0

msgpack==0.5.6

protobuf==3.6.1

pyasn1==0.4.4

pyasn1-modules==0.2.2

pytz==2018.7

requests==2.20.1

rsa==4.0

six==1.11.0

urllib3==1.24.1

Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

I've checked my logs , every dependency package in my requirements file seems to have installed properly without any issues, I'm using apache library and also installed latest mod_wsgi package.... I followed some AWS resources and increased the load balancers' timeout but it didn't fix the issue

I've seen many Stack overflow questions related to these, but didn't seem to find a complete or a concrete answer.I'm creating this question in-spite of that is because I have very few attempts left to deploy in my free tier, so I want to make them count. I highly appreciate your time and efforts in advance.

note: Please ignore the indentations in this code. I manipulated the spacing badly to fit inside the code block.

Thanks

Comment: Guys ?? Anyone ??

Comment: Read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/cors-support.html

Comment: hey did you eventually solve this issue @AmithAdiraju?